# Jackson serialize BasicFileAttributes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize a class that has `BasicFileAttributes` in it. I am using jackson to serialize and deserialize it.

```
  @JsonDeserialize(as = BasicFileAttributes.class)
  private final BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes;
```

Jackson throws error: `abstract type can only be instantiated with additional type information`. However I can't find a concrete class of `BasicFileAttributes`. How do I fix this?

Comment: I would not use interfaces which comes from `JDK` or 3-rd libraries in `POJO` model. You should create custom `POJO` class which has required properties and you should use it in your model to serialise and deserialise `JSON`.

Comment: @andrewjames, have you tried to deserialise given `JSON` to `BasicFileAttributes` and `ObjectMapper` returned `sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributes` instance?

Comment: Deserialization fails, with the same error as described in the question. I should have made it clear that I only serialized. I see (only now) that your question does mention both directions. @MichałZiober

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = JrtFileAttributes.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can't find the class `JrtFileAttributes`

Comment: JDK 14 jdk.internal.jrtfs

Comment: Sorry with the given project setup (jdk) that I can't change, I cannot find this class. Is there any other way? Thanks!